How does Keycloak decide what claims will be included in OidcUserInfo after successful login?
In my Spring Boot project the login function is implemented using Keycloak.
Relevant codes in project are shown below.
public static OidcUser getLoginUser() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser) {
        return (OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    }
    return null;
}

Relevant source codes are shown below.
package org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc;

public class OidcUserInfo implements StandardClaimAccessor, Serializable {
    private final Map<String, Object> claims;
}

How does Keycloak decide what claims will be included in OidcUserInfo after successful login?

It's defined by the "mappers" configured for the client used and requested scopes (configured under clients -> {{clientID}} -> Client scopes -> {{scope}} -> Mappers).
If the built-in mappers are not enough, you can write your own mappers using the SPI.
